# How to Push ViewController in UITableViewCell's @IBAction func

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` and `UITableViewCell` and Cell's XIB Files.

My question is how to push `UIViewController` from cell?

in UITableViewCell.

```
 @IBAction func pushBtnTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        // navigate to post view controller
        let guest = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GuestCollectionVC") as! GuestCollectionVC
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(guest, animated: true)
}
```

I got an error message. `self.storyboard` is not UITableCell's member.

- I know there is another way to implement this. But I have to implement in TableViewCell.

Comment: Check if you have storyboard as the member in your cell?

Comment: Nope, I'm using SlackTextViewController...So I add table's cell by using the code :) Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you'd push from the table view controller, in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method call. Why do you say you have to implement it in the cell? There are other ways you could do that but from what you're saying this might be the best shot...

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("YourSegueId", sender: nil)
```

Then in prepareForSegue

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

//get the index path of the selected row
let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow

//just an example if you want to pass something to the other vc
let item = self.responseItems[indexPath!.row]

if segue.identifier == "YourSegueId" {

        YourVC = segue.destinationViewController as! YourVC

        YourVC.item = item
}
}
```

If you want to do it from the button you could do something like this in the prepareForSegue method... now you have the button and its index path

```
  let button = sender as! UIButton
  let view = button.superview
  let cell = view?.superview as! YourCell
  let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tomorrow I will try your advise and I will be back tomorrow. I'm really appreciate for you.

Comment: I have 3 files.. 1. TableViewController, 2. TableViewCell, 3. TableViewCell.xib and.... button @IBAction is in the xib file... where I put the your code? Thanks